# How can I get Wolfram Development Platform editor to show the text selection in Chrome?

Tags: bugs, wolfram-cloud

How can I get Wolfram Development Platform editor to show the text selection in Chrome?

Here (latest Chrome, Windows 7), it is invisible.

E.g. Here x ^ 2 is selected [image: Screenshot1]

confirmed by Delete press 
[image: Screenshot2] .

Comment: Shows up for me, latest Chrome, Mac OS 10.11.1. Can you give us a screenshot?

Comment: @PatrickStevens on Windows selection only makes text bold. At least for me.

Comment: @Patrick , screenshot added.

Comment: I can reproduce this issue and it has been brought to the attention of the developers of the Wolfram Cloud. Thank you for reporting this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wolfram Cloud has released 1.25.  The issue mentioned here has been fixed for Windows/Chrome. Welcome to try again.

Comment: Thanks - verified. http://i.imgur.com/dgAsFW3.png And now I get a plot too. I have no idea why I didn't before.